# IsEnabled or Enabled?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, naming-conventions

Throughout Silverlight and WPF, properties that are boolean values are prefixed with *Is* ([almost all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding(VS.95).aspx)), for example:

- `IsEnabled`
- `IsTabStop`
- `IsHitTestVisible`

In all other Microsoft frameworks (winforms, BCL, ASP.NET) *Is* is not used. What prompted their team to move away from the original naming convention - is it an evolution or a miss-naming that had to stick?

Comment: Quite related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874350/naming-conventions-for-java-methods-that-return-booleanno-question-mark and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348649/naming-of-bool-methods-is-vs-can-vs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Personally, I always try to prefix boolean values with something that adds a little more meaning (is, has, can, etc.). My usage comes from the following Microsoft guidelines:

> Do name Boolean properties with an
>   affirmative phrase (CanSeek instead of
>   CantSeek). Optionally, you can also
>   prefix Boolean properties with Is,
>   Can, or Has, but only where it adds
>   value.

[MSDN - Names of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx)

<strike>I don't believe this was always the case</strike> This wasn't always the case. Those practices date back to .NET 2.0. Before that, things were fair game. Cleaning up those names in newer versions of the Framework, however, would cause all kinds of headaches (hence some of the Framework code uses the convention and some doesn't).

It definitely makes things more readable though. Even using an example from your question. Which would you rather have?

```
// ambiguous naming, could mean many things
myTab.TabStop
```

or

```
// definitely a true/false value
myTab.IsTabStop
```

Comment: That's interesting that it's a new recommendation, explains most of winforms not having the Is prefix.

Comment: @Chris S - It's hard to get everything right the first time around. This might've been one of the lessons learned from .NET 1/1.1

Comment: For TabStop, "Is" adds clear value: the property's value tells you whether something is a tab stop; the value is not a tab stop itself. For Enabled, the added value is more subtle. "Is" here distinguishes between whether something is enabled and an "enabled", whatever that would be, maybe an enabled copy the object. Another added value is that the object reads more like English: myObject.IsEnabled.

Comment: @EdwardBrey reading "enabled" as a noun would be a stretch for the English language. So I think dropping the "Is" is appropriate here

Comment: @fjch1997 You're right. Noun ambiguity probably isn't the reason. In some other design, differentiation could be required. For example, if you had an immutable `Button`, I could see having `IsEnabled` of type bool and `Enabled` (short for `EnabledButton`) of type `Button` that returns an enabled copy. However, since WPF uses mutable objects, that kind of differentiation isn't required.

Comment: Adding `Is` in front of boolean properties allows adding an event notifying of a positive change without a name conflict. For example, you can have a property `IsEnabled` and events `Enabled` and `Disabled`. That kind of event naming would be consistent with the existing event `FrameworkElement.Initialized`. So perhaps the rationale was to make it clear at a glance that the member was a property, not an event. Or perhaps it was to not preclude adding such events in the future. Or perhaps something else; I'm just speculating.

Answer (score 4):

The `Is` prefix is part of the official Microsoft Framework Design Guidelines (this does not mean that all MS products adhere to it...).

Personally, I find it useful, if consistently used. It immediately tells you that a Property is a Boolean. You might use it or not, the most important thing is to be consistent about it...

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

The `Is` prefix can give a hint about the fact that the property only has a `get` accessor, and, as Thomas and Rachel said, it's a bool. Skip the prefix if you intend to implement both `get` and `set` accessors and its type is other than bool.

Comment: I'll disagree, I know I've set IsEnabled on some objects before. It's probably because it's a boolean value and not something you can set to any value.

Comment: I would tend to agree with that explanation, but many read/write properties in WPF have this prefix... I think it is rather intended to show that the property is a bool

Comment: @Thomas and Rachel - in fact that's what i wanted to say, but i managed to somewhat write something else :)