# Naming convention for Boolean properties

Tags: properties, boolean, naming-conventions

I'm struggeling with the prefixes of my Booleans between **Is-** and **Has-**. 
Because sometimes **Has-** make more sens than **Is-**

Sampe:

```
bool IsPrintable
bool IsChecked

bool HasDocument
bool HasPermission
```

so whats your opinion about that?

Comment: go through this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874350/naming-conventions-for-java-methods-that-return-booleanno-question-mark

it will definitely help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use both. It makes your code much more readable:

`if (IsPrintable) Print()`

`if (HasDocument) Documents[0].Name = 'New Doc'`

Etc.

Answer (score -2):

You could always use `_p`

```
Document_p
Printable_p
```

This derives from an old Lisp convention. "P" stands for predicate, making it basically a form of Hungarian notation. This makes `_p` always precisely true, versus always using `Is` or `Has`, which would be misleading at best.

But seriously: Follow @Ryan's suggestion. Use both.

Comment: i thought Hungarian are again the modern standards of naming conventions like `strText` to say it is a `string` value

Comment: Yes. And predicate is a fancy way of saying bool.