# How can I use the 'has' method naming convention for booleans with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Jackson doesn't handle my boolean fields with a `has` getter method. For example `animal.hasLegs()`, for the `legs` field returns a JSON object without the `legs` field. It does work with the `is` getter method (`person.isAwesome()` for the boolean field `awesome`).

How can I make Jackson use the `has` method naming convention for boolean fields?

Comment: Note: there is no "has" naming convention. The "is" convention is defined in the JavaBeans spec (although even that is an exception), so making getters for booleans with "has", "can", "should" or any other similar prefix is bound to break many applications. Nothing prevents you from creating additional getters though.

Comment: @Kayaman although it might not be official, it is pretty common to use the `has` naming. For example, check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874350/naming-conventions-for-java-methods-that-return-booleanno-question-mark

Comment: It's still not in the spec. If it were in the spec, it would work automatically.

Comment: Having you tried annotating your getters and setters with `@JsonProperty(value="Name of the field")` ?

Comment: Ran into issues with Jackson and `is` naming.  Moral of story... recommend that despite aesthetics , use `get` everywhere for properties.  Avoid `is`, `has`, etc...  coders later will not care that much vs. the hell you'll need to deal with for serialization.  If you really want an extra verb, maybe `getIsSomething()`.  That way your property is at least named `isSomething`.

Comment: Thank you @Kayaman. Finally I found the manual by the keyword "JavaBeans spec" about isXXXXX() naming conventions

Answer (score 5):

1. Annotate all needed `hasXXX()` methods with `@JsonGetter`. Otherwise Jackson doesn't use this property at all, because it doesn't start with `get`:

   ```
   @JsonGetter
   public boolean hasAwesome() { ... }
   ```
2. Set custom `PropertyNamingStrategy`, which renames mapping from method name to JSON field. By default it will generate JSON field named `hasXXX`.

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = ...
   mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy() {
       @Override
       public String nameForGetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName) {
           String prefix = "has";
           if (defaultName.startsWith(prefix)) {
               String withoutHas = defaultName.replace(prefix, "");
               char firstLower = Character.toLowerCase(withoutHas.charAt(0));
               return firstLower + withoutHas.substring(1);
           }
           return super.nameForGetterMethod(config, method, defaultName);
       }
   });
   ```