# Kotlin- naming convention for boolean returning methods

Tags: naming-conventions, kotlin

What is the naming convention for boolean returning methods?

Using an 'is', 'has', 'should', 'can' in the front of method sound ok for some cases, but I'm not sure.
Is there a better way to name such methods?
for example: a function that checks card's validation. Should I call it `isValidCard` or `cardValidation` or another name?
(I didn't find it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin naming style assumes you use the Java naming conventions to the possible extend. I suggest you use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874378/3144601) to the same question about Java.

UPDATE: they have released coding conventions 
http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html

Answer (score 69):

*Something about naming convention for properties in Kotlin, I know it's not for methods. But it's related:*

From book [Kotlin in Action (by Dmitry Jemerov & Svetlana Isakova) - section 2.2.1 Properties](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kotlin-in-action/9781617293290/kindle_split_012.html):

> In Kotlin, properties are a first-class language feature, which entirely replaces fields and accessor methods.

Listing 2.5. Declaring a mutable property in a class:

```java
class Person {
    val name: String,      // read only property: generates a field and a trivial getter
    var isMarried: Boolean // writable property: a field, getter and a setter
}
```

> Kotlin’s name property is exposed to Java as a getter method called
>   getName. The getter and setter naming rule has an exception: **if the
>   property name starts with is, no additional prefix for the getter is
>   added and in the setter name, is is replaced with set.** Thus, from
>   Java, you call isMarried().

Comment: This is much more helpful than the accepted answer -- thanks!

Comment: For reference, this is also documented here: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Answer (score 13):

For those using properties prefixed with `can`, `should`, etc. in mixed Kotlin/Java projects, you can also use [`@get:JvmName`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname) to make the generated Java method more idiomatic for Java clients.

For example, say you have a class like this:

```
class User(

    @get:JvmName("canView")
    val canView: Boolean

)
```

Without the annotation, Java clients would be forced to call `user.getCanView()`, but now they can call the more idiomatic `user.canView()`.