# Kotlin, Java, JSTL Boolean interop

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, kotlin, jstl

I have a problem with JSTL and Kotlin interop.

I have a this particular kotlin class with 2 kotlin Boolean fields.

```
class Foo {
    var isBar1 : Boolean = false
    var isBar2 : Boolean = false

    constructor()

    constructor(isBar1: Boolean, isBar2: Boolean) {
        this.isBar1 = isBar1
        this.isBar2 = isBar2
    }
}
```

I have to acces these two fields from a jsp which i'm doing in the following way:

```
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${foo.isBar1== true}">
          <p>Print something</p>
     </c:when>

     <c:when test="${foo.isBar1== false}">
          <p>Print something else</p>
     </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

And the exact same for isBar2

The problem is, when I run this piece of code
I ran into

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: packagedeclaration.setBar1(Ljava/lang/Boolean;)V

If i try to write the following functions:

```
fun getBar1(): Boolean {
    return this.isBar1
}

fun setBar1(isBar1: Boolean): Any {
    this.isBar1= isActive
    return Any()
}

fun getBar2(): Boolean {
    return this.isBar2
}

fun setBar2(isBar2: Boolean): Any {
    this.isBar2= isBar2
    return Any()
}
```

It will take me to 
"javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [isBar2] not found on type [packagedeclaration.foo]"

I've tried to set fields as private but it did not help.
Java boolean as parameter seems impossible to pass because IntelliJ constantly bombing me with different errors.

Here's my thoughts:
JSTL tries to access java getters/setters with java boolean parameter and return type. 
Jstl looking for methods named with java naming conventions, so getBar1 and setBar1 but kotlin generates isBar1 and setBar1

Java - Kotlin interop for boolean is Boolean according to this kotlin reference page:
[Kotlin- Java interop reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Try without "is"  `${foo.bar1== true}`  for the appropriate matching.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317026/kotlin-naming-convention-for-boolean-returning-methods and see if it helps you in any way. You probably need to use the java getter for your checks inside the JSP template.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt
Thanks for the good tip.
Sadly that didn't solve the problem.
NoSuchMethodExc with- or without the custom setters (and private/ default visibility modifier too)

Comment: In boolean values, `EL` will look for `isBar1()` getter method for `${foo.bar1}` too. Maybe you have JSTL lib problem. Please remove all JSTL tag and tag lib definition top of your page. Just try with EL `${foo.bar1}` to check it whether is properly being invoked or not.

Comment: That was it. Thanks

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt I don't think i can mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt
Thanks, I put a mark on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean values, EL will look for `isBar1()` getter method for expression `${foo.bar1}` too. Probably, you have JSTL lib problem. Please remove all JSTL libs and tag lib definition at the top of your page. Just try with EL `${foo.bar1}` to check it whether is properly being invoked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)** feature of Kotlin here,

Try below

```
data class Foo(val isBar1:Boolean= false,val isBar2:Boolean= false)
```

Comment: I've used Gurkan Yesilyurt solution and it solved the problem